# Create a map of generic list to initialize multiple ComboBox in once

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, generics, types

I would like to create a map with the name of the property object as a key and a list of type object as a value.

In my case I would like to have a map :

```
Dictionary<string, List<Object1 Or 2>> objectToListofObj1Or2 = new Dictionary<string, List<Object1 Or 2>>();
```

I can have either a list of Contact or Adress.

I have a method to initialize my map, right now it is AbstractEntity, a superclass of Adress and Contact :

```
 public Dictionary<string, List<AbstractEntity>> InitializeMapping()
    {
        Dictionary<string, List<AbstractEntity>> objectToListContactCorrespondance1 = new Dictionary<string, List<AbstractEntity>>();
            objectToListContactCorrespondance1["CodeContactFactAchatExterne"] = ContactsFacturationAchatExterne.Cast<AbstractEntity>().ToList();
//my key is the property name, value is my list already created, here is a List of type Contact
            objectToListContactCorrespondance1["CodeContactContractAchatExterne"] = ContactsContractualisationAchatExterne.Cast<AbstractEntity>().ToList();

//here a list of type Adress
objectToListContactCorrespondance1["CodeAdresseContractAchatExterne"] = AdressesContractualisationAchatExterne.Cast<AbstractEntity>().ToList();
```

I do all of this to pre select a lot of rambComboBox with the corresponding CodeAdress or CodeContact inside the list in the view as this :

```
 Dictionary<string, List<AbstractEntity>> mapping = InitializeMappingContact();
foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in dataInit.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if (mapping.ContainsKey(propertyInfo.Name) && (alreadyIn.Where(code => code == propertyInfo.Name).ToList().Count == 0))
            {
                if (mapping[propertyInfo.Name].First().GetType() == typeof(Contact))
                {
                    Contact test = (Contact)mapping[propertyInfo.Name].First();
                    propertyInfo.SetValue(dataInit, mapping[propertyInfo.Name].Count == 1 ? test.CodeContact : null, null);
                }
                else
                {
                    Adresse test = (Adresse)mappingContact[propertyInfo.Name].First();
                    propertyInfo.SetValue(dataInit, mappingContact[propertyInfo.Name].Count == 1 ? test.CodeAdresse : null, null);
                }
            }
        }
```

My map now works, I've added the FIRST(). But my combobox arent' selected with this line (dataInit allows my the initialize the view) :

```
propertyInfo.SetValue(dataInit, mappingContact[propertyInfo.Name].Count == 1 ? test.CodeContact : null, null);
```

Otherwise, if I don't use my foreach and the Initialize method, I have to do it line by line manually like this :

```
dataInit.CodeAdresseContractAchatSVD = AdressesContractualisationAchatSVD.Count == 1 ? AdressesContractualisationAchatSVD.First().CodeAdresse : null;
```

I would like to do :

```
dataInit."mapping[propertyInfo.Name]" = mappingContact[propertyInfo.Name].Count == 1 ? (Adress)mappingContact[propertyInfo.Name].First().CodeAdresse : null;
```

Comment: As a note, `mapping[propertyInfo.Name].GetType() == typeof(Contact)` would better be written as `mapping[propertyInfo.Name] is Contact`

Comment: Why doesn't using AbstractEntity work? What happens when you debug the code?

Comment: I might have found something : my test type is wrong, I need to do : mapping[propertyInfo.Name].FIRST().GetType() == typeof(Contact) or to make the list as corresponding type

Comment: I've updated my post

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had to check if the list in the map wasn't null and then I could get the type of my list:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in dataInit.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if (mappingContact.ContainsKey(propertyInfo.Name) && (alreadyIn.Where(code => code == propertyInfo.Name).ToList().Count == 0))
            {
                if (mappingContact[propertyInfo.Name].FirstOrDefault() != null)
                {
                    if (mappingContact[propertyInfo.Name].First().GetType() == typeof(Contact))
                    {
                        Contact test = (Contact)mappingContact[propertyInfo.Name].First();
                        propertyInfo.SetValue(dataInit, mappingContact[propertyInfo.Name].Count == 1 ? test.CodeContact : null, null);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Adresse test = (Adresse)mappingContact[propertyInfo.Name].FirstOrDefault();
                        propertyInfo.SetValue(dataInit, mappingContact[propertyInfo.Name].Count == 1 ? test.CodeAdresse : null, null);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```